useEffect function is not working as expected
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const incCount = () => {
    console.log("count ", count)

    // setCount(count + 1)
    setCount(x => x + 1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('use effect called')
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => incCount(), 1000)
    return() => {
      // clearInterval(intervalId);
      console.log("clear interval called")
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Counter

In display count is increasing as expected but in console every time it shows 0 only. incCount is executing after every one second and in console count 0 is printing is whereas on screen count is increasing by 1 every time as expected.

In my opinion, the useEffect triggers the setIntrevl function at once. So it runs every second. The initial counts copied the function and ran as expected and added the old state + 1.
If you re-render the component, it will update. Like,


import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const incCount = () => {
    // setCount(count + 1)
    setCount((x) => x + 1);
    console.log("count ", count);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect called");
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => incCount(), 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      console.log("clear interval called");
    };
  }, [count]);

  return <div>{count}</div>;
}

export default Counter;
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



It will trigger the re-render of the component.

Adding count as a dependency completely defeats the purpose of using an interval as you are clearing and re-instantiating the interval each time it runs the callback and updates the count state. Just use setTimeout instead if this is what you want to suggest. See also The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately for the other problem in your code suggestion. Your snippet also doesn't run.

Sorry, I didn't think this point of view. I intend to explain, why the count is always 0. And sorry, I am new to stack overflow. So I don't know how to add and run the code snippet on the answer page. I will correct this. Thank you.

For details on creating stack snippets see this excellent post.

The useEffect hook is running as expected, there's no issue there.
The issue you have is that of a stale Javascript Closure over the count state in the incCount function scope that is passed to the setInterval callback. setInterval gets that initial instance "copy" of incCount that it just calls repeatedly each interval. I never gets a new copy with the updated count state value closed over in scope.
Methods to address:

Use a useEffect hook to console log the count state when it updates. This is the simplest and most trivial.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const incCount = () => {
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(incCount, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("count ", count);
  }, [count]);

  return <div>{count}</div>;
}

export default Counter;


Use a React ref to cache the count state that can be referenced from the closure.
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const countRef = useRef(count);

  const incCount = () => {
    console.log("count ", countRef.current);
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(incCount, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    countRef.current = count;
  }, [count]);

  return <div>{count}</div>;
}

export default Counter;



Note
While you could console.log the current count state value in the setCount state updater function
setCount(count => {
  const nextCount = count + 1;
  console.log("count ", nextCount);
  return nextCount;
});

and there'd be no adverse reaction since console.log is rather benign, you should be aware this is not recommended as the state updater functions are to be considered pure synchronous functions, and technically speaking logging the value is a side-effect and should be avoided.

To understand closure in general, and in addition of the answer of Drew Reese, you can pass the latest state via a ref also, as in this example.
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const incCount = () => {
    console.log('count', count); // 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
    setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  useInterval(incCount, 1000);
  return <>{count}</>;
}

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const callbackRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    function callbackWithLastState() {
      callbackRef.current();
    }
    if (delay) {
      const id = setInterval(callbackWithLastState, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

export default Counter;

As a result the log inside incCount will show the last count state.

In your React component, the incCount function is using the count variable from its initial render, which remains constant at 0 in the console log. The setCount call updates the state correctly, so the displayed count increments as expected, but since the count variable inside incCount doesn't update between renders, it logs 0 every time.
To see the updated count in the console each time incCount is called, you should log the count state within the setCount callback function. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve that:


import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const incCount = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => {
      const newCount = prevCount + 1;
      console.log("count ", newCount);
      return newCount;
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('use effect called');
    const intervalId = setInterval(incCount, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      console.log("clear interval called");
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Counter;



In this updated code, the console.log statement is placed inside the setCount callback, which receives the most recent state value (prevCount). This ensures that the console logs the updated count each time incCount is called.
